# CSS and raster fonts, disabling anti-aliasing for monochrome output

Tags: css, antialiasing, monochrome

I'm using Awesomium to turn self-contained HTML files into images that are meant to be printed on a monochrome printer that doesn't support grayscale.

How do I make it so that fonts are rendered with no anti-aliasing, so they will look as smooth when printed as they do on screen?

There used to be an option `-webkit-font-smoothing`, but it appears to have been removed a while ago, and does nothing in either Chrome or Awesomium.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?  I was just about to post the exact same question on the Awesomium Q/A site.

Comment: Not to use Awesomium. I ended up using http://theartofdev.com/html-renderer/ , which is good enough for my purposes.